# LP problem: Giving variables the same value or 0

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming, constraints, constraint-programming

If I have the following objective function:

$$\min X_1 + X_2 + X_3 + X_4$$

How could I ensure that the variables $X_1, X_2, X_3$ and $X_4$ either have the value of 0 or they could have a random other value but only that value. So in total 2 different values may be assigned to the variables 0 or another value.  It is difficult to formulate it well I think this example will make more sense:

The following solution is feasible: 
$X_1 = -5$
$X_2 = 0$
$X_3 = -5$
$X_4 = -5$
Every solution with maximal 2 different values in which 0 is one of these values should be feasible. The other value that should be assigned is not known beforehand.

Comment: are you saying that all of the $x_i$ should be either $0$ or any other value $a$, but that value should be the same across all $x_i$ and should be picked by the optimizer?

Comment: Yes that is what I am saying, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let $y$ be that unknown value, and introduce it as a variable in your optimization program.

You can introduce constraints $x_i (x_i - y) = 0$ which will force $x_i=0$ or $x_i=y$. Note this makes your problem nonlinear. Is this ok or you are interested in linear solution only?

Comment: I was interested in a linear solution, because the problem is too large to solve if it is non linear.